# WCF: How to change the processing order of messages?

Tags: wcf

My wcf-service must process messages from clients in a specific order. If messages contain the same tag (defined, for example, as a parameter of the operation), these messages must be processed sequentially, they can not be processed simultaneously in different threads. Messages with the same tag may be obtained from different clients. How to implement this requirement?

Comment: are you talking about concurency here i.e message with similiar tag must not be processed concurently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an integration design pattern called [Resequencer](http://eaipatterns.com/Resequencer.html) which describes what you will need to do to implement ordered delivery for your messages.